# Unresolved reference 'graphene_django'

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-django

I just started working with `GraphQL`, `Django` and `Graphene`.

I was attempting to import `GraphQLView` and `DjangoObjectType` from `graphene_django`

but it always says

> unresolved reference

I did already installed the needed modules with `pip install graphene-django==2.8.2`, and the `Virtual environment` is up and running.

```
#settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'books',
    'graphene_django',
]
```

I couldn't get `graphene_django` to import properly.
What are the possible fixes to this?

Comment: going through the same issue

Comment: does the venv is set as your interpreter?

Comment: @Sevy yes and it is, well I just figured it out, I installed the package manually from the package manager!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the issue:

1. navigate to your preferences (settings)
2. go to 'Project'
3. python interpreter
4. click add on the packages list
5. in the package manager search for `graphene_django`
6. install -> apply

and you should be good to go.

[image]